# Need more clarification of the CSS syntax

Tags: html, css

In CSS block:

```
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover{
  outline:none;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

does this mean:

"The hover effect applies to the `a` tag in the `navbar-custom`'s sub class `nav` list element?"

If no, please clarify.

Comment: Yes you're right. That is what nesting means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're interpreting it correctly.  A space between selectors means that style will be applied to any descendants of the parent selector that match.  So for `.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover`, any anchor elements that are descendants of list items that are descendants of elements in the `nav` class that are descendants of elements in the `navbar-custom` class would have that particular style applied on hover.

If you used a bracket instead of the space (i.e. `.navbar-custom > .nav > li > a:hover` then the style would only apply to *direct descendants* of each selector, rather than any descendants.

Answer (score 1):

.navbar-custom .nav li a... Are the element selectors. This selector is applying style to the anchor tag within the other element listed in order.

for example

```
<div class="navbar-custom">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="">link somewhere</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link somewhere</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link somewhere</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no I understand that. I just need to know what does .navbar-custom .nav li a translates to?

Comment: This is selecting the <a href="">link somewhere</a>(anchor) element